# Discord event causing commands to not function - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im fairly new to programming and thought a good learning project would be a discord bot for a personal server all hosted on heroku. but ive hit a snag that id like to ask for some help with.

this event here is causing all other commands not to function at all and i cant quite understand why:

```
import discord
import time
import os
import asyncio
import random

from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '~')

Messages = ['1', '2', '3','4']

@client.command()
async def Load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def Unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def Reload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is Online')

async def change_status():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    status = cycle(Messages)

    while not client.is_closed():
        current_status = next(status)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=current_status))
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        print ('Status Changed')

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Missing required argument')
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send('Command does not exist')
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send('You do not have permission to use this command')

###################################################################################
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author.id
    if message.author.id == XXXXX:
        if "gif" in message.content:
            responses = ['This part works','']
            await message.channel.send(random.choice(responses))
###################################################################################

@client.command()
async def Commands(ctx):
    await ctx.send('shows commands')

@client.command()
async def Test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('command works')

client.loop.create_task(change_status())
client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

for context i have a friend that likes to use gifs to convey their opinion to the annoyance of everyone so the aim is to send a message whenever they do. the piece of code im having a  problem with is between the hashes.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
await client.process_commands(message)
```

to the beginning of your on_message function.
on_message takes priority and will always cancel out commands if you don't include this line.

Comment: thank you so much that worked a treat, such a simple fix to the problem. Feel a bit stupid now

Comment: Ah, don't worry 'bout it. I made the same mistake myself